# What is difficult about unifying PKSC11 cards under EU eIDAS?

Tags: pkcs11

Europe issues PKSC11 cards to it's citizens. [Countries have a number of solutions](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskEurope/comments/qkjery/what_is_the_state_of_qualified_electronic/) for eIDAS Qualified signatures, but they are not uniform.

Would it be difficult to build a standard tool that can read and use every EU smart card to sign documents uniformly? What are the underlying difficulties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is largely due to political and not technical reasons, but there are some technical reasons as well.

1. **Reuse of existing organizational processes and infrastructure.** Sometimes, EU guidelines are akin to a standard, and other times, merely a list of requirements a solution has to fulfill. In case the EU merely demands some interface, countries will tend to use their own solutions, which best suit their individual needs.

   If then there would be a call to merge solutions and to make one EU-wide standard, countries would definitely push to have a solution which is most compatible with their already existing design, perhaps even arguing to make their design the standard.

   [image: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png]
2. **Not Invented Here Syndrome.** Most countries exhibit a sense of national pride, which may sometimes lead them to do less-than-optimal things. [Not Invented Here Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) can be one of these, where a country refuses to use a standard by a different country, solely based on the fact that it wasn't developed here.

   As I stated in the previous point, nationally-developed solutions tend to be tailored to the needs of the nation. Should a different nation have slightly different needs, even if their needs would align 95%, they may use this as a "rational justification" to reject the proposed solution by the other country and instead develop their own solution.
3. **Politics isn't about finding efficient solutions.** Instead, politics is mostly about marketing oneself. If someone in a high-ranking office decided that "We developed our own solution!" made for a better, more compelling narrative than "We worked together with the other EU countries to develop an EU-wide standard", then that way will be the preferable one.